# What's the difference of double a[] and double[] a in cython?

Tags: python, cython

```
cdef public int myfun(double x, double y, double z[], double[] k):
    z[0] = 1.2
    z[1] = x + y
    k[0] = 1.2
    k[1] = x + y
    return 0
```

Do they belong to different types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. Just different ways of declaring the same type of array. The syntax of which is inherited from C.

Comment: really? I cannot find reference that c allows `double[] k`

Comment: @colinfang That form is probably the more official but Cython-specific form. It lets you do things like `cdef char[] *thing` which would be much less clear in C. Unless you have a good reason, use the `T[] x` form.